# How to add a single color surface mesh below a transparent grid

Tags: gnuplot

gnuplot includes a bewildering number of options which I have not yet assimilated.
The code displays a single colored grid below a transparent plane. Light coloring of the lower grid does make it apparent it is below the plane. As the lower grid intersects
the plane on exactly two edges, the grid must be curved. Perhaps displaying
the grid with an interpolated mesh will make that clearer.

a) How to make a mesh for he lower grid?

b) Is there a better way to color with a single color, i.e. not use a palette?

```
# Try to add colour to mask

set terminal wxt size 600,600 enhanced font 'Verdana,10' persist
a=57344; b=-6976; c=1785856; d=-173228032
set cbrange[0:1]
set palette defined (0 'blue', 1 'light-blue')
set dgrid3d 5, 5
set style data lines
splot 'mask.dat' with pm3d, -(a*x+b*y+d)/c

reset
```

data file: mask.dat

```
0 0 97
0 256 94
0 512 91
0 768 88
0 1024 85
436 0 83
436 256 81
436 512 79
436 768 77
436 1024 75
872 0 69
872 256 68
872 512 67
872 768 66
872 1024 65
1308 0 55
1308 256 55
1308 512 55
1308 768 55
1308 1024 55
1744 0 41
1744 256 42
1744 512 43
1744 768 44
1744 1024 45
```

Answer (score 0):

The coloring is fine like you did it, don't know a better method.

To plot a grid for the lower mesh, just redraw the data without `pm3d`:

```
reset
set terminal pngcairo size 600,600
set output 'test.png'
a=57344; b=-6976; c=1785856; d=-173228032
set cbrange[0:1]
set palette defined (0 'blue', 1 'light-blue')
set dgrid3d 5, 5
set style data lines
set ticslevel 0
unset colorbox
unset key
splot 'mask.dat' with pm3d, '' lc rgb 'blue', -(a*x+b*y+d)/c lt 1
```

Result (with 4.6.4):

[image]